# Three dimensional projective space $\mathbb{RP}^3$

Tags: reference-request, projective-geometry, projective-space

I need to refresh my mind.

I'm looking for detailed courses (or tutorials) about the three dimensional projective space $\mathbb{RP}^3$ and practical applications to computer visions and computer graphics.

Thanks

Comment: Are you clear about the difference between the two- and three-dimensional real projective spaces?

Comment: Do you know OpenGL?

Comment: I'm almost clear about RP2, duality between points and lines, lines joining points, homogeneous coordinates... There is a lot of courses about RP2 too.

Comment: I use OpenGL everyday but rasterization is just one application.

Comment: UC Davis ECS175 - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_w_qWAQZtAZhtzPI5pkAtcUVgmzdAP8g - discusses matrices in computer graphics from at the latest lecture 4 on. For 3D space you use 4 homogeneous coordinates and a 4x4 matrix, treated either as the action of the linear endomorphisms of 4D space on projective 3-space (by removing 0 from 4D space & making points equivalent to their nonzero scalar multiples) or as a notation for projective transformations of projective 3-space (still constructing projective 3-space by removing the origin and taking equivalence up to nonzero scaling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very nice book, easy to understand, with a very extensive chapter on $\mathbb{RP}^3$.

Here's the link (chapter 12) : http://www-m10.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/Lehre/WS0910/ProjektiveGeometrieWS0910/GeomBook.pdf

Maybe people interested by $\mathbb{RP}^3$, projective spaces and geometric interpretations should also take a look at Grassmann algebra (at the same time Plücker coordinates).

This book draft is really a good start : https://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/thegrassmannalgebrabook/GrassmannAlgebraBook.pdf?attredirects=0

Answer (score 1):

An Introduction to 3D Computer Vision Techniques and Algorithms by Boguslaw Cyganek and ‎J. Paul Siebert can be a good book. Search on google books to see the preview.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.

Comment: It seems this book focuses on $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Do you own a copy ?